# Tags field not rendered in rendering variant

Tags: sxa

I'm using SXA and am trying to get the tags to render in a rendering variant.  I've added a variant reference to my tags field and added a title field item so that the tag title will render to the page. I've added variant references before with no problem, but I get nothing in my page. Any ideas?

My defined tags:

[image]

The tags selected in the item I'm rendering in my rendering variant:

[image]

My rendering variant definition:

[image]

My variant reference definition:

[image]

My field definition for to render the tag title:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is actually called "`SxaTags`" - try that in the "`Pass through field`". I think that should fix your issue.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped to solve your issue.. ;)